# Pandas multiindex creation performance

Tags: python, pandas, performance, multi-index

Performance tests for creating equal `pd.MultiIndex` using different class methods:

```py
import pandas as pd

size_mult = 8
d1 = [1]*10**size_mult
d2 = [2]*10**size_mult

pd.__version__
```

```py
'0.24.2'
```

Namely `.from_arrays`, `from_tuples`, `from_frame`:

```py
# Cell from_arrays
%%time
index_arr = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([d1, d2], names=['a', 'b'])
# Cell from_tuples
%%time
index_tup = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(d1, d2), names=['a', 'b'])
# Cell from_frame
%%time
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':d1, 'b':d2})
index_frm = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df)
```

Corresponding outputs for cells:

```py
# from_arrays
CPU times: user 1min 15s, sys: 6.58 s, total: 1min 21s
Wall time: 1min 21s
# from_tuples
CPU times: user 26.4 s, sys: 4.99 s, total: 31.4 s
Wall time: 31.3 s
# from_frame
CPU times: user 47.9 s, sys: 5.65 s, total: 53.6 s
Wall time: 53.7 s
```

And let's check that all results are the same for the case

```py
index_arr.difference(index_tup)
index_arr.difference(index_frm)
```

All lines produce:

```py
MultiIndex(levels=[[1], [2]],
           codes=[[], []],
           names=['a', 'b'])
```

So why is there so big difference? `from_arrays` is almost 3 times slower than `from_tuples`. It is even slower than create DataFrame and build index on top of it.

**EDIT:**

I've done another more generalized test and result was surprisingly the opposite:

```py
np.random.seed(232)

size_mult = 7
d1 = np.random.randint(0, 10**size_mult, 10**size_mult)
d2 = np.random.randint(0, 10**size_mult, 10**size_mult)

start = pd.Timestamp.now()
index_arr = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([d1, d2], names=['a', 'b'])
print('ARR done in %f' % (pd.Timestamp.now()-start).total_seconds())

start = pd.Timestamp.now()
index_tup = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(d1, d2), names=['a', 'b'])
print('TUP done in %f' % (pd.Timestamp.now()-start).total_seconds())
```

```py
ARR done in 9.559764
TUP done in 70.457208
```

So now `from_tuples` is significantly slower though source data are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example makes more sense to me. Looking at the source code for Pandas, [`from_tuples` actually calls `from_arrays`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a6a1ab20e1fd3b9c54308f852a4427846b0695da/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L511), so it makes sense to me that `from_arrays` will be faster.

`from_tuples` is also doing some extra steps here that cost more time:

1. You passed in a `zip(d1, d2)`, which is actually an iterator. `from_tuples` [converts this into a list](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a6a1ab20e1fd3b9c54308f852a4427846b0695da/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L494).
2. After it was converted to a list of tuples, it goes through an extra step to convert it to a [list of numpy arrays](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a6a1ab20e1fd3b9c54308f852a4427846b0695da/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L506)
3. The previous step [iterates through the list of tuples twice](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6e3537dbab2b5d6344e969cf3ae18925acf745e9/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L2461), making the `from_tuples` significantly slower than `from_arrays`, right off the bat.

So overall, I'm not surprised `from_tuples` is slower, since it has to iterate through your list of tuples an extra two times (and do some extra stuff) before even making it to the `from_arrays` function (which [iterates a couple more times](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/a6a1ab20e1fd3b9c54308f852a4427846b0695da/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L433), by the way) that it uses anyways.

Answer (score 1):

[`from_tuples`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.5/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L430) converts [iterators to lists](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.5/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L540-L541), then [lists to arrays](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.5/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L555), then [arrays into lists of arrays](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.5/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L555), then ultimately calls [`from_arrays`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.5/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L560) on that.